# pygame can't load image

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))

my_image = pygame.image.load(r'/Users/Humberto/documents/python/games/alien')
posX, posY = 200, 150

window.blit(my_image, (posX, PosY))


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()


    pygame.display.update()
```

I am trying to load an image that is in the same folder and it will return an error saying pygame.error: Couldn't open /Users/Humberto/documents/python/games/alien I have tried writing the .png extension, also writing the whole path using / and // and also tried the raw string. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Can you open the image in another program?

Comment: pygame.error: Couldn't open /Users/Humberto/documents/python/games/alien

Comment: You definitely need to include the extension in the path, whether it's full or not.

Comment: Are you on linux or windows or mac?

Comment: it is a png file I am trying to run the code in the terminal

Comment: I am using mac.

Comment: get path `/Users/Humberto/documents/python/games/alien.png` and try to use it in different program - image viewer. Maybe problem is some upper/lower case name. And always show in question full error message (traceback). There can be more usefull information.

Comment: now I guess - you need upper `D` in word `Documents`

Comment: It returned false

Comment: Yes, file and folder names are case-sensitive on OSX and Linux.

Comment: So I upper case everything and is now True but when I try to run it it returns this error pygame.error: Failed loading libpng.dylib: dlopen(libpng.dylib, 2): image not found

Comment: Rather than hardcode a path, you can extract the folder name of the currently running script with `folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)` and then use it with `image_path = os.path.join(folder, 'alien.jpg')` to get a full path to the file (if the image is in the same folder as the script).

Comment: I don't think the Mac port of pygame supports Python 3. See the _Macintosh_ section on the [pygame download page](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml).

Comment: Should I use python 2?

Comment: If you want to use pygame you'll need to use Python 2. You'll also need to install the Python from python.org.

Comment: Alternatively, the instructions on the page titled [_Installing Pygame for Python 3 on OS X_](http://florian-berger.de/en/articles/installing-pygame-for-python-3-on-os-x/) might be useful.

Comment: Thank you @martineau i followed the instructions and now it works and with python 3!!

Comment: De nada — our goal is to help when we can. `;-)`